# Quand on utilise simplement « avec » et quand « avec de » ?

Tags: prépositions

Quand utilise-t-on simplement *avec* plutôt que *avec de* ?

Par exemple :

> Un nouvel événement est disponible, avec de précieuses directives en guise de récompenses !

Je pense qu'on ne doit pas mettre de virgule. Je veux écrire comme ça :

> Un nouvel événement avec de précieuses directives en guise de récompenses est disponible !

Mais je ne suis pas sure que le *de*  soit nécessaire.

Comment: This seems to be a common issue for people learning french considering the amount of questions similar to this one asked on this website. I'll redirect you here : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28914/why-de-in-%c3%a0-de where they answered your question for "à de" instead of "avec de", but the same rules apply for both cases.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Il y a un exemple sans verbe :

" Un nouvel événement est disponible, avec de précieuses directives en guise de récompenses ! "

Moi, je pense qu'on doit pas de virgule. Je veux écrire comme ça :

" Un nouvel événement avec (de?) précieuses directives en guise de récompenses est disponible ! "

Comment: Je pense que la première phrase est grammaticalement correcte telle quelle :) en revanche je ne sais pas d'où elle sort mais son sens m'échappe...

Comment: This is a notification in the game.
The meaning is following:
"New event with valuable blueprints as a reward is available!"

Answer (score 1):

Le **de** est obligatoire.

Le sens n'est pas bien clair (ou c'est de l'ironie). En quoi des directives sont une récompense ?

On peut utiliser deux formes

- *la première*: Un nouvel événement est disponible, avec de précieuses directives en guise de récompenses !
- *apposition*: Un nouvel événement - avec de précieuses directives en guise de récompenses - est disponible !
- on peut remplacer les tirets à la rigueur par des virgules, mais c'est plus clair avec des tirets.

Answer (score 0):

Normalement, il y a un article après *avec*. Dans les cas ci-haut, je crois que de est nécessaire. Il y a quelques exceptions. Elles sont listées sur http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/081.html celle qui s'applique avec *avec* est:

avec (valeur d’adverbe) : avec lenteur

Mais on peut quand même ajouter l'article:

- avec plaisir
- avec un très grand plaisir

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 0):

L'article défini n'est pas présent lorsque le nom abstrait se tient seul après une préposition, formant une phrase adverbiale.

> Ex. Il accepta avec joie. Il le fit par amitié. Sans hésitation.

En particulier, **avec** introduit des compléments circonstanciels indiquant la manière, l'instrument, etc.

> Ex. Je te défendrais avec courage.

Lorsque le nom abstrait est qualifié par un adjectif, il est précédé au singulier par un ou une, et au pluriel par des.

> Ex. Une voix d'une puissance étonnante. Il fait des progrès remarquables.
> Il enseigna avec un goût prononcé de pédagogie.

Il y aussi quelques nuances :

> Répondre avec sourire.
>
> Répondre avec un sourire inattendu. (réponse et
> sourire simultanément !)
>
> Répondre d'un sourire / par un sourire (answer by smiling).

Comment: "Répondre avec sourire" n'est pas correct. Il faut dire "répondre avec *un* sourire". Ensuite tu peux qualifier le sourire comme tu veux.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat   Si je me rappelle bien je l'ai vu dans un livre de grammaire. Je vais le corriger quand même. Merci.